# Share variables among functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have code like:

```
MyClass = {

   init: function(){
   marker = 0;
   //I call foo() and bar() from here
   },

   foo: function(){
   //I want to access & update marker here
   },

   bar: function(){
   //This function also accesses updates marker
   }
};
```

I can access the `marker` by passing it as a parameter to functions but I will not be able to update it.

So, how do I manage creating a variable `marker` such that all three functions can share it? I don't want to write any code outside `MyClass`.

Comment: Try making `marker` a property of `myClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `marker` in MyClass, not in init, where it is right now.

```
MyClass = {
   // marker is in MyClass now
   marker: 0,

   init: function(){
      console.log(this.marker);
   //I call foo() and bar() from here
   },

   foo: function(){
   //I want to access & update marker here
   },

   bar: function(){
   //This function also accesses updates marker
   }
};
```

Comment: I am getting `Expected ':' and instead saw '='.` in jslint when I do that. (on the line at which I declare marker = 0)

Comment: @shadyabhi: It should be `marker: 0`, just like the other properties.

Comment: Thanks. It was pretty easy. I will except the answer in next 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyClass = {
   marker: 0,

   init: function(){
     this.foo();
     this.bar();
     console.log(marker);
   },

   foo: function(){
     marker = 4;
   },

   bar: function(){
     marker = marker * 2;
   }
};
```

If you execute `MyClass.init()`, it prints 8 in console.